# Java Custom Object creation using assignment operator

Tags: java

I want to create my custom object using the assignment operator as the string does.

For example,

If I want to create an Object of employee class in a simple way like -

```
Class Employee{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private String country; 
}

Employee employee = "Bagesh,27,India";
```

So is it possible to create an object the same way String class creates? or anyone can suggest the internal working of string assignment operator object creation.

I have already searched for it on many links but didn't get a complete answer.

Comment: The answer is no. It's not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assignment Operator Overloading Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129284/assignment-operator-overloading-java)

Comment: Your best bet would be to create a constructor.

Employee employee = new Employee("Bagesh",27,"India");

Comment: Only String literals can be created using assignment operator like this. Custom objects needs to be created via Constructors. 

String message = "Hello World";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

The `String` class is special in Java. The compiler has special knowledge about it and knows how to generate byte code for e.g. the `=` operator (assign reference to a preallocated string in the String pool) and `+` operator (call `.concat()`).

Answer (score 3):

> So is it possible to create an object the same way String class creates? [...] `Employee employee = "Bagesh,27,India";`

No, you can't do that. You'd need some form of operator overloading (either assignment overloading, or overloading of string quotes), and none of that is possible in Java.

You can do:

```
Employee employee = new Employee("Bagesh,27,India");
```

Though that would be odd, you might as well split your string up and do:

```
Employee employee = new Employee("Bagesh",27,"India");
```

If you wanted something a bit shorter, you could delegate to a separate method with a short name:

```
Employee employee = fromStr("Bagesh",27,"India");
```

...and implement `fromStr()` to call your constructor, though there's very little point in taking that approach in this example.

Other "flavours" of the above are all possible - factory classes, static factory methods, etc. - but none of them will give you the syntax you've defined in your question.