# Is it possible to have values for class object in java, if yes how can we acquire it?

Tags: java, function, class, object

Let's say, I am initializing a class obj as follows:

```
<class> obj = <some value>;
```

Is it possible to initialize as such I mean we initialize String and primitive values like that, But I mean for any class. And how can we get them so they can be used in some method of the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if it is for built in types like string, int, float etc. These built in types are pass by value. Which means if you say `int a = 5`, `5` is copied over to memory location.

If you are asking about your class, I do not think so. Unlike `C++` you cannot overload operator. Another reason why you cannot do this is objects are pass by reference, meaning

```
MyClass myObject = <someValue>;
```

`<someValue>` is not copied to memory where `myObject` lives, instead reference (address of) it is. Thus, you need to have `new myObject()`.

One disclaimer you can do this:

```
MyClass objA = new MyClass();
MyClass objB = objA;
```

but it is still copying reference not the actual values from `myObj`.

OP please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129284/assignment-operator-overloading-java).

While I think from some aspect this question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129284/assignment-operator-overloading-java), I think the levels of knowledge between OPs of these questions is so far apart that I am not going to flag it.